# Script to list the files of a folder and export it to a text document

Tags: windows, file, export, directory

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way that you could get all the folders, files and sub-folders of a location (such as C:\Users\Username) and export it to a text document on a network share (such as \server\share\document.txt).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the command line (or use a batch file if you're going to need this a lot):

```
dir c:\users\username > \\server\share\document.txt
```

that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The following command will show all files in the specified directory and all sub-directories and redirect the output to a file on a server share.

```
dir /s c:\Users\Username > \\server\share\document.txt
```

Add the /b option if you want to see the files with the full path included in the file name.

```
dir /s /b c:\Users\Username > \\server\share\document.txt
```